# Как открыть порт для выбранного компьютера на openwrt (по MAC адресу или другой путь)

Tags: iptables, настройка, доступ, openwrt, порт

Имею роутер с `OpenWRT 17.04`. Нужно открыть порт `80` для одной машины где заранее знаю мак адрес.

Правила в iptables выглядят как:

```
WAN='eth0.2
iptables -A input_rule -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 80  -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j ACCEPT
```

где

`XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` - MAC адрес машины которая пытается получить доступ к админке

```
WAN='eth0.2
iptables -A input_rule -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Работает, но только для всех машин.

Но почему то не пускает меня. Что не так делаю? Спасибо заранее за ответ.

Comment: вы упоминаете tcp-порт. протокол tcp работает непосредственно поверх ip. вот ip-адрес у вас и должен быть указан. и никак иначе.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тоесть ip адрес внешний? А как бы если захожу с любого места где есть интернет и ip адрес разный (за ранее не могу знать какой будет внешний адрес). В случае с MAC это может быть

Comment: ip-адрес, по которому ваш компьютер доступен для маршрутизатора.

Comment: хм, извините не совсем понимаю. Суть в том чтобы иметь возможность получить доступ к роутеру по внешнему ip адресу который предоставляет провайдер. А так как буду подключаться удаленно то адрес будет все время меняться, по маку было бы надежней

Comment: интернет — это сеть, построенная на **ip**-протоколе. компьютеры связываются между собой по **ip**-адресу.

Comment: p.s. добрый совет, к которому можно не прислушиваться: прежде чем фантазировать на тему «а вот было бы классно, если бы можно было так  или эдак», очень неплохо бы прочитать хоть пару википедийных статей соответствующей тематики. [1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82) и [2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да вы правы мак здесь не причем. Спасибо за совет и за ссылки.Открыл новый вопрос по теме, може поможешь [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849360/) спасибо заранее